# Java Security Manager: Specify Jar File in JVM Args

Tags: java, security

I am making a Minecraft Control Panel in which members can run their own jar files on our servers which could have potentially damaging consequences to our equipment.

I would like to set a jar file (I code java) which will be the security manager. I would like to do this so I can prevent some operations, e.g. only 1 socket to 1 IP so they dont use it to perform a denial of service attack.

I know there is a java.policy file, but this isnt "smart" enough to allow you to do some of the operations I would like to do.

I know you can override the security manager, but then the class would be loaded within the same JVM and another malicious code could override this manager.

My question to you, is how can I make a security manager that nobody elses code can possibly interfere with.

Answer (score 0):

> I know there is a java.policy file, but this isnt "smart" enough to allow you to do some of the operations I would like to do.

If you're control of the command line, just specify `java -Djava.security.manager ...`. If you're not in control of the command line, *take* control of it. Or take control of the JVM and call `System.setSecurityManager(new SecurityManager());` before it does anything else such as running client JAR files.

> I know you can override the security manager, but then the class would be loaded within the same JVM and another malicious code could override this manager.

Not sure what this means. Once a security manager is installed it cannot be replaced.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Isnt -Djava.security.manager only for a java.policy file? Or can you put a jar file there for a Security Manager